# ～てみると in this context

Tags: grammar

speaker invited to go into his girlfriends house for the first time, had previously walked her back home a few times

> 今日初めて彼女の家に行く事になった。
>
> **家の場所は送って行ったりしたおかげで知っていたけど家の前に来てみると、どうしたら良いのかよくわからなくなってしまっている。**
>
> 友達の家に遊びに行くのとは違い、すごくドキドキする……
>
> (I know that?) Maybe it’s because I walked her home before, once I try to come to their doorstep, i've become utterly clueless on what to do now.

I have hard time reading what he is trying to get at with in the second statement with ...知っていたけど家の前に来てみると, ...

Is knowing "家の場所は送って行ったりしたおかげで" suppose to result in "家の前に来てみると、どうしたら良いのかよくわからなくなってしまっている。"?

is 知っていた referring to something else?

or does this usage of てみると apply here?

[「てみると」「てみれば」「てみたら」の三語はほぼ同じように使われる。無意志性の動詞や自然現象を表わす動詞を受けて、その状況が成立した時に、の意味を表わす表現である。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17235/meaning/m0u/)

thank you

Comment: I think it's parsed as: 家の場所は(送って行ったりしたおかげで)知っていた i.e. he knew the location of the house thanks to ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like he is trying to say that "Even though I know the location of the house because I escorted (the girl), if I try coming before it, it has become that I don't know what is the best to do".

> 送って行ったりしたおかげで

Because escorted (and other)

> 家の場所は 送って行ったりしたおかげで知っていたけど

Even though I know, the place of house, because (I escorted)

> 家の前に

Before the house

> 来てみると

If I try to come.

So "Even though I know, the place of house, because (I) escorted, if I try to come before the house..."

Comment: I think it's `when` not `if`.

Comment: Could work regardless :D